# Subfolder in controller prefixes Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have next structure:

```
Controllers
   Epic
     PmController.cs
   HomeController.cs
```

in my App_Start\RouteConfig.cs I added: **Update** - added full method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Epic",
      url: "Epic/{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Pm", action = "Index" }
  );
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

But somehow @Url.Action is always prefixed with "Epic". I'm using @Url.Action in other views/controllers like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Links", "Home")">Links</a></li> // generates /Epic/Home/Links instead of just /Home/Links
```

LInks worked ok before adding this subfolder and route.

Additionally is it ok to use subfolders in Controllers or always use [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you removed the default route, just add it again in your RouteConfig file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: I was already included, forgot to add it to my post. I updated my post now. Thank you.